# Claim not added to token in Identity Server 4

Tags: identityserver4

I implemented Identity Service ProfileService to add an Address claim:

```
public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context) {
  
  User user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.Subject);

  ClaimsPrincipal principal = await _claimsFactory.CreateAsync(user); 

  ClaimsIdentity identity = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;

  identity.AddClaims(
    new List<Claim> {
      new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Address, "My Address")
    }
  );

  var claims = identity.Claims;

  context.AddRequestedClaims(identity.Claims);

}
```

I added a breakpoint and claims has the Address claim.

But the token does not have the Address claim.

What am I missing?

**My IdentityServer4 Configuration**

```
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
    options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
})
  .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(
    new List<IdentityResource> { 
      new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
      new IdentityResources.Profile(),
      new IdentityResources.Email(),
      new IdentityResources.Address()
    }
  )
  .AddInMemoryApiResources(
    new List<ApiResource> { 
      new ApiResource {
        Name = "api",
        DisplayName = "API Resource",
        Enabled = true,
        Scopes = { "api" },
        UserClaims = { JwtClaimTypes.Address }
      }
    }
  )
  .AddInMemoryApiScopes(
    new List<ApiScope> { 
    new ApiScope("api", "API Scope")
    }
  )
  .AddInMemoryClients(
    new List<Client> { 
      new Client {
        ClientId = "spa",
        ClientName = "SPA Client",
        AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
        AllowOfflineAccess = true,
        RequireClientSecret = false,
        RequireConsent = false,
        RequirePkce = true,
        AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
        AccessTokenLifetime = 3600,
        IdentityTokenLifetime = 360,
        RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse,
        AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
        UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true,
        AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
        AllowedScopes = { 
          IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
          IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile, 
          IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email, 
          IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
          "api"
        },  
        AllowedCorsOrigins = { "https://localhost:5002" },
        PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5002/signout" },
        RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5002/signin", "https://localhost:5002/renew" }
      }
    }               
  )
  .AddAspNetIdentity<User>()
  .AddProfileService<ProfileService>()
  .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
```

**Update**

I added the following IdentityResources:

```
new IdentityResources.Address(),
new IdentityResource("subscription", new String[] { "subscription"})
```

Then I updated the SPA client by adding the two Scopes:

```
IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Address,
"subscription"
```

Finally, when using OidcClient.js I requested these two Scopes.

Because the ASP.Net Identity adds these 2 claims I will get them on the token.

But in case ASP.NET Identity does not add the claims, if I try to do it in the ProfileService they are not added to the token. Any idea why?

I am missing the purpose of the IS ProfileService as the claims are not being added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your user has the `address` claim then it will get added to their profile automatically as long as you include the `address` scope when signing in.

Edit: If the claim required is associated with an api resource, then it will not be returned in the profile, but rather in the `access_token`. So if you want to see the user's address you have to include it in an identity resource instead.

Comment: I will be glad to elaborate on this answer if you provide more details.

Comment: I kind of made it work but I am still a little bit confused about the claims not being added in the ProfileService. Any idea why? I just added an update.

Comment: Does the user have the requested claims? If the user does not have the claim the profile service will not add it to the user info.

Comment: Yes, the User has the Claims. But when the User has the Claims and I request those Scopes the ProfileService is not needed for the Claims to be included in the Token. So you're saying that the Profile Service is just to change the Claims values that the User already has and that are requested and not to add or delete claims to the token? this is confusing.

Comment: You are calling `AddRequestedClaims` the address claim is not a requested claim for the userinfo endpoint, it is only requested as part of the access token creation. If you notice the `GetProfileDataAsync` is called with a "context" that can be "userinfo" and can also be other things.

Comment: In short, step through the code with the debugger and verify that the address claim is actually requested for the relevant endpoint call ("UserInfoEndPoint" i think)

Answer (score 1):

You should add the Address scope to the list of the AllowedScopes in your client defintion:

```
    AllowedScopes = { 
      IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
      IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile, 
      IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email, 
      IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
      "api"
    },
```